# How to add headers to columns

Tags: sed, cat

I have data:

```
7456 7456 0 0 0 2
7463 7463 0 0 1 2
```

I want to add column headers so the output is:

```
FID IID PAT MAT SEX PHENOTYPE 
7456 7456 0 0 0 2
7463 7463 0 0 1 2
```

I have tried `echo -e "FID\tIID\tPAT\tMAT\tSEX\tPHENOTYPE" | cat file1 > file2`

But this is copying the original file and not the headers.

```
sed '1i\FID, IID, PAT, MAT, SEX PHENOTYPE' file1 > file2
```

has the error

```
sed: 1: "1i\FID, IID, PAT, MAT,  ...": extra characters after \ at the end of i command
```

Any advice please?

Comment: try `echo -e "FID\tIID\tPAT\tMAT\tSEX\tPHENOTYPE" | cat - file1 > file2`

Comment: ... or `(echo ....; cat file1) > file2`.

Answer (score 19):

Your try with

```
echo -e "FID\tIID\tPAT\tMAT\tSEX\tPHENOTYPE" | cat file1 > file2
```

is nearly functional, but `cat` won't do anything with its standard input (containing the actual headers). The following will work:

```
echo -e "FID\tIID\tPAT\tMAT\tSEX\tPHENOTYPE" | cat - file1 > file2
```

`cat` will interpret `-` as standard input, and will insert the output of `echo` before adding on the contents of `file1`.

An alternative:

```
{ echo -e "FID\tIID\tPAT\tMAT\tSEX\tPHENOTYPE"; cat file1; } >file2
```

or

```
( echo -e "FID\tIID\tPAT\tMAT\tSEX\tPHENOTYPE"; cat file1 ) >file2
```

Answer (score 18):

This GNU `sed` adds the text as the first line in the file:

```
sed  -i '1i FID IID PAT MAT SEX PHENOTYPE' test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the append operator instead `>>` :

```
echo -e "FID\tIID\tPAT\tMAT\tSEX\tPHENOTYPE" > file2 && cat file1 >> file2
```

Answer (score 2):

This error

> sed: 1: "1i\FID, IID, PAT, MAT,  ...": extra characters after \ at the
>   end of i command

occurs because you are on OSX (I think), and you should have a newline after `\` as [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and GNU `sed` allows that. like

```
sed '1i\
my headers' infile
```

Or alternatively use:

```
sed -e '1i\'$'\n''my headers' infile
```

Also if you need in-place you should have `-i ''` instead of only `-i` (on OSX or FreeBSD).

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your data is space delimited as you've shown. The following will do the formatting and get what you want.

```
awk -vOFS="\t" '$1=$1; BEGIN { str="FID IID PAT MAT SEX PHENOTYPE"; split(str,arr," "); for(i in arr) printf("%s\t", arr[i]);print}' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the ugly

```
echo -e "FID\tIID\tPAT\tMAT\tSEX\tPHENOTYPE"
```

you could use

```
head=( FID IID PAT MAT SEX PHENOTYPE )
( IFS=$'\t'; echo "${head[*]}"; cat file ) > file2
```

which localizes changes to the global IFS variable into a subshell